# Django CMS conditional

Tags: django-cms

How do I use a conditional in Django CMS in base.html to detect if the page is the home page and add a unique class to the body tag? I'd prefer to not duplicate base and just add a class so I can handle some styles differently on the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you structure your pages.

I opt for creating pages as a child of the 'home' page so use something like this for page titles;

```
{% if request.current_page.get_ancestors|length <= 1 %}
    <h1>{{ request.current_page.get_page_title }}</h1>
{% else %}
    {% for ance in request.current_page.get_ancestors %}
        {% if ance.depth == 2 %}
            <h1>{{ ance.get_page_title }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So you could do something like;

```
<body class="{% if request.current_page.get_ancestors|length <= 1 %}base{% endif %}">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @DebbieGray No problem, happy to help :)